# Auto-complete ip & url in terminal

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to auto-complete previously used IPs and URLs (web) in the command-line? I'm using bash currently.

Comment: Short answer: no. You can search through bash history, that's probably the closest solution

Answer (score 1):

Well the fish shell used interactively will remember entire commands used of which ip and url commands would be a subset. Fish shell will show you a previously run command in another color ahead of what you are typing in the terminal. to install run sudo apt-get install fish. by running the fish command you can start a fish shell and then autocomplete basically anything you want. running help will get you a lot more options.